# $\sum a_n$ converges, $b_n$ is monotonic and bounded, prove $\sum a_n b_n$ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Why I can't do:

$$\sum a_n b_n \le \sum a_n K$$

when $K$ is the bound of $b_n$ and then use the comparsion test, since $\sum a_n$ converges and therefore $\sum a_n K$ does too?

I've found [Why is my proof wrong? (Rudin Ch 3 #8) If $\sum a_n$ converges, and if ${b_n}$ is monotonic and bounded, prove that $\sum a_n b_n$ converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675832/why-is-my-proof-wrong-rudin-ch-3-8-if-sum-a-n-converges-and-if-b-n-i) but mine uses the comparsion test, and this one uses epsilon delta definition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That works if you know all the terms are nonnegative.  If some $a_n$ might be negative, though, then your inequality may not be true, since $b_n\leq K$ does not necessarily imply $a_nb_n\leq a_n K$, and in any case such a term-by-term bound would not tell you $\sum a_nb_n$ converges if the terms aren't all nonnegative.

(Note that you very much need to use the assumption that $b_n$ is monotonic.  For instance, if $a_n=(-1)^n/n$ and $b_n=(-1)^n$ then $\sum a_n$ converges and $(b_n)$ is bounded but $\sum a_nb_n$ does not converge.)